# Implementing checkin/checkout for custom version control

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, tfs

hi all
I want to implement a simple custom version control (windows desktop application) to manage our shared folder that we use it as an shared archive folder.this shared folder contain word documents,text files,images, and other types.I know the sharepoint provide this feature but we want it to be a desktop application not web application.

One feature I have no Idea how to implement in .NET. This feature is the checkIn/checkOut like TFS and sharepoint.

I hear that there is an API for TFS but I dont know if I can use it for this purpose.

I need your recommendation about Implementing checkin/checkout for custom version control.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why a desktop application? Is it just for the user interface?  If so, you can use sharepoint through windows explorer: http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1412

If not, there are several free source/version control applications out there (e.g. SVN) that have integration to Windows Explorer they may be suitable for you.

Unless there is something specific missing from what is out already, no need to recreate the wheel....

Comment: yes it just for user interface.and thank you for notify me about this feature in sharepoint .
but I want some thing available for small business with out need to purchase sharepoint.

Comment: Use Mercurial, Git, or Subversion. Don't roll your own - that's a really bad idea.